# Added Column to Table Not Updating

Tags: android, sqlite

I created a table And successfully added a column using the Command

```
ourNewDatabase.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + tbname + " ADD " + key_day + " VARCHAR(10);");
```

But on Updating any row with newer values, all column value for that particular row except the added column (key_day) get updated.. Tried Many Times.. But No Solution.. The command for Updation is :

```
ContentValues cvUpdate = new ContentValues();
cvUpdate.put(KEY_STUNAME, "AHIHUOI");
cvUpdate.put(KEY_STUROLL,"109rty890");
cvUpdate.put(key_day,"false");
String stuuid = "20130801001";
int ans = ourNewDatabase.update(tbname, cvUpdate, KEY_STUUID + "= '" + stuuid+"'", null);
```

Comment: On Alter Table Execution, all rows get the default value equal to key_day ..my key_day value for example is - '12_3'

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading your database by incrementing the database version number.